Flutter IOS Archiving giving error, 'Multiple commands produce GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy.bundle. XCODE 15.4
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cccxxxxbxtrddshhkhjfkteujcckfyz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy.bundle'
note: Target 'GTMSessionFetcher-Core-GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cccxxxxbxtrddshhkhjfkteujcckfyz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy.bundle'
note: Target 'GTMSessionFetcher.default-Core-GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cccxxxxbxtrddshhkhjfkteujcckfyz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher_Core_Privacy.bundle'
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cccxxxxbxtrddshhkhjfkteujcckfyz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
note: Target 'GTMSessionFetcher-Core' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cccxxxxbxtrddshhkhjfkteujcckfyz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
note: Target 'GTMSessionFetcher.default-Core' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cccxxxxbxtrddshhkhjfkteujcckfyz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
I tried removing and updating pods. checked Copy bundle resources under build phases, nothing is working.

After 3 days, I solved it by adding pod 'GTMSessionFetcher' in all the targets in podfile.
target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher'
flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(FILE))
target 'RunnerTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end
end
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
end
end
target 'ImageNotification' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher'
end

Had similar problem when I had to fix Firebase bugs which got to production (don't rely on Firebase, kids)
After upgrading deployment target from 13 to 14 and Firebase libraries like Auth and Messaging, similar error started happening. Fixed by adding GTMSessionFetcher to ImageNotification target, and I did not have to add it to Runner.
Here is full Podfile:
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  pod 'GoogleTagManager', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  fix_deployment_target(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    # Start of the permission_handler configuration
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      #  Preprocessor definitions can be found in: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler_apple/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
  
        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
          
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   
           
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
   
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
   
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
      ]
  
    end 
    # End of the permission_handler configuration
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
end

def fix_deployment_target(installer)
  return if !installer
  project = installer.pods_project
  project_deployment_target = project.build_configurations.first.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']

  puts "Make sure all pods deployment target is #{project_deployment_target.green}"
  project.targets.each do |target|
    puts "  #{target.name}".blue
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      old_target = config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']
      new_target = project_deployment_target
      next if old_target == new_target
      puts "    #{config.name}: #{old_target.yellow} -> #{new_target.green}"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = new_target
    end
  end
end

